# ActiveRecord relation does not convert to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a scope in my model

```
class AllowanceandBenefit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  #belongs_to :salary_payroll
  scope :regular_allowances, ->(month) { where(is_regular: true, month_nepali: month) }
  scope :onetime_allowances, ->(month) { where(is_regular: false, month_nepali: month) }
end
```

And I want to use that scope from another payroll model where the method is

```
  def calculate_allowances
    self.total_monthly_income += AllowanceandBenefit.regular_allowances(nepali_month).amount +
                                 AllowanceandBenefit.onetime_allowances(nepali_month).amount
  end
```

But this does not work because AllowanceandBenefit.regular_allowances(nepali_month) returns ActiveRecord Relation object and it is giving me following errors when I tried applying methods like .to_a, .to_json

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
: SELECT "allowanceand_benefits".* FROM "allowanceand_benefits" WHERE "allowanceand_benefits"."is_regular" = $1 AND "allowanceand_benefits"."month_nepali" = $2
from /home/rabin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:611:in `async_exec_params'
```

I have searched through stackoverflow and google but could not come up with the solution that works.
Also it would be nice if someone could tell me if there is some nice way to merge those two scopes into one so I wont have to write two scopes for each state of boolean field. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try `AllowanceandBenefit.regular_allowances(nepali_month).or.onetime_allowances(nepali_month).sum(&:amount)`

Answer (score 1):

Please try below query

```
AllowanceandBenefit.regular_allowances(nepali_month).or.onetime_allowances(nepali_month).sum(&:amount)
```

Comment: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Answer (score 0):

Pass two argument in the scope. Second argument can have true, false, or both [true, false].

```
class AllowanceandBenefit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  #belongs_to :salary_payroll
  scope :onetime_regular_allowances, ->(month, is_regular) { where(is_regular: is_regular, month_nepali: month) }
end

class PayRoll < ApplicationRecord

  def calculate_allowances
    self.total_monthly_income += AllowanceandBenefit.onetime_regular_allowances(nepali_month).sum(&:amount)                                  
  end

end
```